# Birt Report Designer Shortcut keys

Tags: birt, keyboard-shortcuts

Anybody know if there's shortcut keys to run/view reports in BIRT Report Designer?

[image: Pic]

Comment: I'm having similar issues. The icon for the "web viewer" in the toolbar keeps disappearing. The only solution I've found to this, is select WINDOW -> NEW WINDOW which will reset the icons in the toolbar. However, it does disappear again after some time I've found.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>  <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run in the default web viewer. You could also use arrow keys to select your output format.

To see a list of other shortcuts type: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to find a hotkey, so I ended up doing a workaround and used Autohotkey: http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/36468-birt-report-designer-shortcut-keys-for-view-report/

Answer (score 0):

Pressing Alt, R, R, then Enter will do it.

Here's an autohotkey snippet that will make F5 do the same:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe eclipse.exe  ;BIRT
;BIRT F5 to Run Web Viewer
F5::
Send {Alt}
Send r
Send r
Send {enter}
Return

#IfWinActive
```